# Delay in custom action

Tags: wix, wix3.8

We have used Custom Action in our application (WIX). Normally while installing setup, this custom action will take around 20 mins to complete. But one of our customer machine it takes to 15 hours to complete.

We have attached the log file details for custom action start and end details. Can anyone please tell why this issue occur in some of the machine ?

**Log:**

```
Action start 14:02:14: REMOVE_DLL.
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\Windows\Installer\MSI9D80.tmp-\
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v2.0.50727
Calling custom action Info.MysampleRemoveAll!Info.MysampleRemoveAll.CustomActions.RunMysampleConsole_RemoveAllVersions
MSI (s) (2C:1C) [17:21:32:257]: Running as a service.
Action ended 5:07:50: REMOVE_DLL. Return value 1.
Action start 5:07:50: INSTALL_DLL.
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIB833.tmp-\
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v2.0.50727
Calling custom action Info.MysampleInstall!Info.MysampleInstall.CustomActions.RunMysampleConsole_InstallVersion
Action ended 7:54:59: INSTALL_DLL. Return value 1.
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Can you post a readable version of the log?  What is the operating system of the target machine?  What does the custom action do?

Answer (score 0):

The operating system of the target machine is Windows 7(64bit). Custom action will remove the assemblies from the GAC location.